# Convert hair to mesh

Tags: mesh, particles, export, hair

I am new to blender, I come from a Cinema 4D background. I am trying to export the hair from Blender as a mesh but it isn't working.

I tried the "convert to mesh" button under the modifiers tab for the hair object but it doesn't export.

I bought this file and I just need the hair as a mesh to import into c4d. How can I accomplish this?

This is a downloadable version of the .blend file with the hair
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lc7yplk4ksij0gd/hair.blend?dl=0

Textures: [textures\Hair-length.png](https://tinyurl.com/3pfwpkud)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: When I open your file in Blender 3 I see there is a hair particle system. But the model has no hair. It doesn't show up. It's shown in *Comb* mode.  But no editing was done. The *Simplify* option is enabled but you didn't lower the default settings so it has no effect and doesn't hide the hair. Is it bugged? I guess because there is no hair you can't convert it. If I delete and recreate the particle system the hair shows up.

Comment: I am very new to blender but I have been working with c4d for almost 10 years. I have no idea how to resolve the issues you stated but the file I uploaded is a minimal version of the full character. I just deleted everything except the hair. This file renders the hair perfectly, the way I want it. 

I am not sure why you had that error but after you recreated the particle system, does the hair show up? Is it possible to export a mesh to c4d?

Comment: Hmm, can you upload a screenshot? This is what I see when I open your file (https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DrtA.jpg). It's Blender 3.0 file. The pink color means there is an image texture missing. Images are external files & not included in the blend file. But this all should not matter. I hadn't tried a render. Now I tried but there is no hair as you can see. I've also removed the black background. No hair. By the way, don't go so high with the strand settings. 10 means 2^10 and creates a memory peak of almost 2 GB. A value of 5 is totally fine=77 MB peak =>https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjZXQ.jpg

Comment: Ah! You're using a texture to control the hair length. But it's missing. That's why I see no hair. Can you upload the texture? (//textures\Hair-length.png)

Comment: When you press *Convert to Mesh* Blender creates an object called *Mesh* in the collection named "*set*". Maybe you missed it? With the strands option set to 10, it's 2.5 million vertices. With 5 it's 677k.

Comment: Hey Blunder, thank you for the replies. I didn't know the hair was driven by a texture, I uploaded 2 files: #1 the texture file (https://tinyurl.com/3pfwpkud) and #2 I packed the resources into a .blender file (https://tinyurl.com/yc49td92)

Comment: @Blunder Thanks for the tips regarding strand settings. When I tried to convert the hair particles to curves and then add a bevel, it crashed my computer because the vertices count when to 27 million. I will try to reduce the strand count and reconvert to curves and then bevel it again. After which I can convert back to mesh.